# Stability of $\operatorname{Sym} T^2$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

It is known that the tangent bundle $T$ on $\mathbb{P}^2$ is stable. Is the symmetric power $\operatorname{Sym} T^2$ stable?

I know it is a vector bundle of rank $3$ with Chern character $(3,9,21/2)$. One can also find a resolution of it using line bundles [see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/120870/symmetric-power-of-tangent-space.). But I do not know how to prove or disprove its stability.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using `\operatorname{Sym}` to format $\operatorname{Sym}$ will produce better spacing. I've made the upgrade to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check stability one can use Hoppe's criterion --- for a vector bundle $E$ of rank r it amounts to verifying that
$$
H^0(\mathbb{P}^2, \wedge^p E(-a_p)) = 0,
$$
where $1 \le p \le r-1$ and $a_p$ is the minimal integer such that the slope of $\wedge^p E(-a_p)$ is nonpositive.

In the case of $E = \operatorname{Sym}^2 T$ using the isomorphism
$$
\wedge^2 \operatorname{Sym}^2 T \cong \operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega(9)
$$
the criterion reduces to the computation of
$$
H^0(\mathbb{P}^2, \operatorname{Sym}^2 T(-3))
\quad\text{and}\quad
H^0(\mathbb{P}^2, \operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega(3)).
$$
The first is a direct summand in $\operatorname{Hom}(T,T) = \Bbbk$, while the other summand is
$$
H^0(\mathbb{P}^2, \wedge^2 T(-3)) = 
H^0(\mathbb{P}^2, \mathcal{O}) = \Bbbk,
$$
hence it is zero. The same argument shows that the other space is zero as well. Therefore, $\operatorname{Sym}^2 T$ is stable.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you explain why $$
\wedge^2 \operatorname{Sym}^2 T \cong \operatorname{Sym}^2 \Omega(9)
$$ is true?

Comment: @RustZ: This is a particular case of the isomorphism $$\wedge^2 E \cong E^\vee \otimes \det(E)$$ which holds for any vector bundle of rank 3 and is induced by the natural pairing $\wedge^2 E \otimes E \to \det(E)$.